# Animation ends right away and doesnt run UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

My code here does not run at all. I want to have an animation of a progress bar going down and I start the progress bar at 1.0 and i want it to go to 0 from right to left. How can I accomplish that? This just runs and ends right away. Thank you

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 15, animations: {

                        //if (self.answerButtonOne.isSelected == true || self.answerButtonTwo.isSelected == true || self.answerButtonThree.isSelected == true || self.answerButtonFour.isSelected == true  ){
                            //self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                        //}
                    }, completion: { (Bool) in
                        if Bool == true{
                           self.disableButtons()
                            self.showRightChoice()
                            let wrong:Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "wrong")
                            let newWrong = wrong-1
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(newWrong, forKey: "wrong")
                            self.whichImage(newWrong: newWrong)
                            self.gameOver()
                            self.wasButtonClicked = true

                        }
                        self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
                    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var timer = Timer()
    var totalDuration = 150.0 // to run it smooth 150/10 = 15

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

          self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.decrementProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      }
      @objc func decrementProgress() {
        if totalDuration == 0 {

        }else {

            self.totalDuration -= 1
            self.progress.setProgress(0.0066 * Float(self.totalDuration) , animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` ... updated my code check it now

Comment: that makes my whole page animate, I'm just looking to animate a progress bar, Am I messing something up?

Comment: then instead of  `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` call `self.progressView.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: can you share your view hierarchy ? i which view you have `progressView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213375/discussion-between-jawadali-and-captaiond-dfsdf).